# Why is this click function not firing even when using 'on'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a question list in which people can add their own categories and questions. This works only for the first one, if I keep adding categories then the ability to add questions stops working.

I've changed my `.click` function to an `on.("click")` but this gave no result.

Everytime I create a new category I add one to `i`, I then add this number to my question add button and use that combination as my id to fire the function.

My code:

```js
// Category
var i = 1;
$('#addcategory').click(function() {
  i++;
  $('#dynamic_field').append('<div class="row" id="row' + i + '"><div class="col-md-8"><ul class="categorylist"><li><input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="' + i + '. Voeg een categorie toe" class="form-control name_list" /><div class="row" id=questionrow"' + i + '">  <div class="col-md-8"> <ul class="questionlist">  <li> <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list" />  </li> </ul>  </div>  <div class="col-md-4"> <button type="button" name="addquestion" id="addquestion' + i + '" class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>  </div> </div></li></ul></div><div class="col-md-4"><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></div>');
});
$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
  var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
});

// Question
var e = 1;
$('#dynamic_questionfield').on("click", "#addquestion" + i + "", function() {
  e++;
  $('#dynamic_questionfield').append('<div class="row" id="questionrow' + e + '"> <div class="col-md-8"> <ul class="questionlist"> <li> <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="' + e + '. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list"> </li> </ul> </div><div class="col-md-4"><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + e + '" class="btn btn-danger removequestion btn_remove">X</button></div></div>');
});
$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
  var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#questionrow' + button_id + '').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dynamic_field">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <ul class="categorylist">
        <li>
          <input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een categorie toe" class="form-control name_list" />
          <div id="dynamic_questionfield">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <ul class="questionlist">
                  <li>
                    <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list" />
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <button type="button" name="addquestion" id="addquestion1" class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button type="button" name="addcategory" id="addcategory" class="btn btn-success">Extra categorie</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh I didn't know that. I read somewhere that with .on your button will work even after the dom is loaded.

Comment: `"#addquestion"+i+""` is the same as `"#addquestion"+i`.

Comment: Only if you use the delegating form. `.on("click", function() { ... })` isn't the delegating form.

Comment: There's no element with id `dynamic_questionfield` in this loooong string you're appending to DOM, so element with id=`"addquestion"+i` is not child of `dynamic_questionfield` for i > 1

Comment: @barbsan Makes sense, so I changed it with the answer on this page, and used `document` instead of `#dynamic_questionfield` but I am still not able to add new questions, only on the first one.

Comment: @twan maybe because you have there `$('#dynamic_questionfield').append(/*code for new question*/)` ? You append it anyway to that element that is only in first question.

Comment: @twan when you add category, you should append to `ul .categorylist` some `li` element that would be similar to first `li` element in that list - just with other ids and extra button to remove category. And after you append it, assign listeners to new buttons. The same rule for questions: append `li` elements to proper `ul .questionlist`

Answer (score 1):

If your element `#dynamic_questionfield` is dynamic, replace

```
$('#dynamic_questionfield').on("click","#addquestion"+i+"", function(){
```

with

```
$(document).on("click","#addquestion"+i+"", function(){
```

Comment: I am still not able to add new questions with above changes.